# JSF swallows closing tag after SVG

Tags: jsf, svg, xml-parsing

I'm using two `<svg>` elements inside a `<ul>`.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

...
<ul>
    <li>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >...</svg>
    </li>
    <li>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >...</svg>
    </li>
</ul>
...
</html>
```

JSF is swallowing the first closing `</li>` when it's rendering the HTML.

Is this a bug or is my xhtml invalid?

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.7.

**Update:** As @BalusC suggested I reported this to [the Mojarra Guys](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/2972).

**Update 2:** Fixed with Mojarra [2.1.26](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES/fixforversion/16620) and [2.2.3](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES/fixforversion/16622)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce it in 2.1.24. I'm not sure if this is a bug in Facelets' SAX parser but it indeed look much like that it got confused in nested namespaces. You're with `<svg xmlns>` declaring a new default XML namespace which has seemingly overriden the `<html xmlns>` one for HTML tags. I recommend to [report](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/) this issue to Mojarra guys.

In any case, the right way of using SVG in Facelets is to split off the whole `<svg>` content into its own `.svg` file and include it via `<ui:include>`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ui:include src="/resources/svg/one.svg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <ui:include src="/resources/svg/two.svg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

This way the namespacing works fine. Additional benefit is, your SVGs are this way instantly reusable.

Comment: Thanks a million for rechecking this! I [opened a ticket](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2968). Just one more question about the svg included via `<ui:include>`: must this file start with `<ui:composition>` and should `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` be the default namespace or would you just place the svg "as is" in the file?

Comment: No, just standard SVG syntax (without doctype) is fine.

Comment: For anyone still looking at this, @BalusC fixed it for us it seems - not sure when the fixed version comes out?