# JSF - SVG doesn't align inside panelGrid

Tags: jsf, svg, primefaces

I'm working on a project that was necessary to use SVG to build a chart, cause primefaces doesn't have the specs that I need to use.
So, what I did to make that is basically use that tag
$ xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

and that code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" >
                <h:panelGroup layout="block">

                    <svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
class="graph" aria-labelledby="title" role="img"> 

                    </svg>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGrid style="width: 100px; ">

                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGroup  id="graficoTeste">

                    <svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
class="graph" aria-labelledby="title" role="img"> 

                    </svg>
                </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The svg works fine. The problem is that when i put the svg inside the panelGroup, my panelGrid stop to align my content side by side and put everything like if it was columns="1".

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: _"Anybody has an idea? "_ Yes, look at the *client-side generated html* and see if you can explain from there... JSF in this regard is 'just' an html generator

Comment: Ty for answer!!

Comment: Proper solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875593/jsf-swallows-closing-tag-after-svg)

Answer (score 0):

I found what's going on.
If you are having the same issue, try to delete this "xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" for the properties of the svg tag.